# How to ignore whitespace in regular expression matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a list with the following keywords:

```
["mark", "anthony", "joseph smith", "michael",...]
```

I want to create a regex delimited by a `|` so that I have something like:

```
mark|anthony|joseph smith|michael
```

I'm doing this like...

```
StringJoiner regex = new StringJoiner("|");
words.forEach(regex::add);
String matcher = regex.toString();
```

However there is an issue when I use this approach. If I have the following strings I want to match on:

```
"josephsmith is unique"
"joseph smith is unique"
```

I want both scenarios to match. What can I add to my code to ignore the whitespace?

I was thinking to maybe use `replace(" ", ...)` on every keyword to replace the spaces with some sort of regex but I'm not sure how that would work with escaping characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your regex string to

```
mark|anthony|joseph\s*smith|michael
```

i.e. replace all spaces with `\s*` to match zero or more whitespace characters.  If you want to match ONLY space (0x20) then make it

```
mark|anthony|joseph *smith|michael
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [answer of @Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66426856/5515060), if you want to apply the mentionted regex to every keyword you could do that with `Stream` from [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

```java
String regex = words.stream()
    .map(word -> word.replaceAll("\\s+", "\\s*"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

The `\s+` matches 1 or more white spaces and replaces them with the literal string `\s*`. (In the final regex `\s*` will match 0 or more white spaces).

Also note that `replaceAll()` accepts a regex as the first argument where as `replace()` will not.